# CURL not working in Docker Image [Unable to access the host in Docker image]

Tags: docker, go, curl, docker-compose, handshake

Docker File

```
# Start from the latest golang base image
FROM golang:latest

# Add Maintainer Info
LABEL maintainer="Sumit Thakur <sumitthakur@yahoo.com>"

# Set the Current Working Directory inside the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy go mod and sum files
COPY go.mod go.sum ./

# Download all dependencies. Dependencies will be cached if the go.mod and go.sum files are not changed
RUN go mod download

# Copy the source from the current directory to the Working Directory inside the container
COPY . .

# Build the Go app
RUN go build -o testapp myapplication.go testapp.go

# Expose port 50051 / for internal comunication 

ENV PORT 50051
RUN echo $PORT

EXPOSE ${PORT}

# Command to run the executable
CMD ["./testapp"]
```

Build Docker file with

```
docker build -t testapp  -f Dockerfile .
```

that's perfect working

Run Docker file

```
docker run -d -p 50051:50051 testapp
```

that's will also working fine

I check with the running container

```sh
docker ps
```

this will give me

```sh
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                      NAMES
57cd3c01bcda        testapp           "./testapp"       2 seconds ago       Up 2 seconds        0.0.0.0:50051->50051/tcp   gracious_bhaskara
```

and when i check the network inspect with

```sh
docker network inspect bridge
```

this will give me

```
[
    {
        "Name": "bridge",
        "Id": "30850a823d3040e7d8eaf804c122ce3d26b35650f6f792cf1f4ce77d66167eeb",
        "Created": "2020-02-19T07:34:24.993299775Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.17.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "57cd3c01bcda3fbf7d0bf67136ebbb8afb312c4f6ca70eeee15cda6e10fff4e2": {
                "Name": "gracious_bhaskara",
                "EndpointID": "2a42056609e8140d190f1efde41320138867d3905053e7f381bd91b1f053c251",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.bridge.default_bridge": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4": "0.0.0.0",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.name": "docker0",
            "com.docker.network.driver.mtu": "1500"
        },
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

Everthing works fine
Except when i trying to connect the docker host

```sh
curl -H "Content-type:application/json" -X GET 'https://localhost:50051/testapp/v1/order'
or
curl -H "Content-type:application/json" -X GET 'https://172.17.0.2:50051/testapp/v1/order'
```

it gives me

```sh
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, GET is already inferred.
*   Trying 0.0.0.0...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 0.0.0.0 (127.0.0.1) port 50051 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* error:1400410B:SSL routines:CONNECT_CR_SRVR_HELLO:wrong version number
* stopped the pause stream!
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) error:1400410B:SSL routines:CONNECT_CR_SRVR_HELLO:wrong version number
```

Test openssl:

```
openssl s_client https://localhost:50051/testapp/v1/order -connect localhost:50051
```

Result:

```
CONNECTED(00000005)
4488771180:error:140040E5:SSL routines:CONNECT_CR_SRVR_HELLO:ssl handshake failure:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-22.200.4/l
ibressl-2.6/ssl/ssl_pkt.c:585:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 0 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID: 
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 
    Start Time: 1582109828
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

Application Code

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "net/http"
    "github.com/gorilla/handlers"
)
func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/testapp/v1/order", testHandler)
    headersOk := handlers.AllowedHeaders([]string{""})
    http.ListenAndServe(":50051", headersOk)
}
func testHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    io.WriteString(w, "Heyyy!")
}
```

Anyone Help I'm stuck here 1-2 days don't know what to do ?

Comment: Are you able to curl the endpoint inside the container?

Comment: yes if i do `docker exec -it <name> bash` and execute  `./testapp` and then i hit curl it will give me the result

Comment: I don't understand why i'm not able to curl from system. I just stuck there.

Comment: Please, use `curl -H "Content-type:application/json" -X GET 'http://localhost:50051/testapp/v1/order' -v` and post the output. Have a look on the log server side. Probably you hit `http` instead of `https`.

Comment: thanks,it will now show's me `curl: (35) LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to localhost:50051 `

Comment: Can you include the actual application code that's setting up the network listener in the question?  It matters what the bind address is, and if there's TLS-related setup.

Comment: Hi @DavidMaze i update the application code in above please check its a basic server code in golang.

Comment: If your server binds to `localhost` as you've shown it will be inaccessible from outside the current container.  Try changing the bind address in the `ListenAndServe` call to `:50051` with no specific host (or to `0.0.0.0:50051` to match the pattern in other languages).

Comment: i did that but it shows me now `curl: (35) error:1400410B:SSL routines:CONNECT_CR_SRVR_HELLO:wrong version number`

Answer (score 1):

From the discussion in the comment, the problem seems related to the `https` handshake.

A simple solution, is to query the service using the following URL:

```sh
curl -H "Content-type:application/json" -X GET 'https://localhost:50051/testapp/v1/order' -v -k
```

Using the `-k`, you are going to ignore the `HTTPS` validation.

***NOTE***: i've changed the URL from `http` to `https`.

Comment: it will give me now `curl: (35) LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to localhost:50051 `

Comment: are you sure that you are using the `https` site instead of the `http`? In this case, please run these command and post the output: `openssl s_client https://localhost:50051/testapp/v1/order-connect` and `gnutls-cli https://localhost:50051/testapp/v1/order`

Comment: I update input/output for openssl s_client in above. Please check

Answer (score 0):

From inside the container, you need to listen on all interfaces, not localhost or the loopback interface. Networking is namespaced in docker, so you get not only a new private ip, but also a separate loopback interface inside the container that cannot be reached externally. To do this, change:

```
http.ListenAndServe("localhost:50051", headersOk)
```

To:

```
http.ListenAndServe(":50051", headersOk)
```

Comment: yeah i changed that i'll update above but this when i hit curl it will give me `curl: (35) error:1400410B:SSL routines:CONNECT_CR_SRVR_HELLO:wrong version number`

Comment: @SumitBon there's no SSL configured here, go back to your original curl command from your question, http, not https.

Comment: i did that but here's the problem i'm facing if i run the curl inside the **docker container** it works fine but from **system** it gave me result `curl: (7) Failed to connect to 0.0.0.0 port 50051: Connection refused` **doesn't understand why this happens**

Comment: @SumitBon your original command did not curl to `0.0.0.0`, it was to `localhost`, use the original curl command.

Answer (score 0):

1. The code provided on `main.go` does not start TLS, so stop tring to curl with `https`, it won't works.
   curl with `http` will work

   ```
   package main

   import (
       "io"
       "net/http"

       "github.com/gorilla/handlers"
   )

   func main() {
       http.HandleFunc("/testapp/v1/order", testHandler)
       headersOk := handlers.AllowedHeaders([]string{""})
       http.ListenAndServe(":50051", headersOk)
   }
   func testHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
       io.WriteString(w, "Heyyy!")
   }
   ```
2. The command `openssl s_client https://localhost:50051/testapp/v1/order -connect localhost:50051` confirm to you that TLS is not present on the port you requested
3. Lot of comments confirm that using `https` is not relevant, again TLS is not activated on your code
4. `curl -H "Content-type:application/json" -X GET 'http://localhost:50051/testapp/v1/order'` works.
   That confirm again TLS is not used

**Conclusion:**

Do not try to curl `https` when TLS is not activated on your code

Comment: thanks i got your point totally understand but here's my problem everything goes perfect except if i run the curl inside the container it works fine but from system it gave me result `curl: (7) Failed to connect to 0.0.0.0 port 50051: Connection refused`